# How can I get an if-statement that takes multiple cin inputs to recognize an error if only the first cin input is incorrect?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, cin

I am building a program that is meant to store values from day-of-week/value pairs into a vector, and then display and sum the values for each day of the week. Therefore, I am asking the user to enter both a string (day of the week, which can be in 4 different forms for each day of the week) and an integer (a corresponding value) for each cin input. (The program only shows Monday and an exit condition so far; I will later build it out to include Tuesday through Sunday as well.)

The program is also meant to identify incorrect input (and allow the user to retry their input). However, I am having trouble getting the program to recognize erroneous input if only the day of week is entered incorrectly. For instance, the program will successfully announce "Incorrect day of week detected" if I enter "test test" as the input. It will also announce this message (even though the wording needs to be tweaked) if I enter "Monday x." However, if I enter "Test 5," the program accepts this without displaying the "Incorrect day of week" message.

How would it be possible to change my program so that, using the pre-existing else statement, it displays "Incorrect day of week" when I enter something like "Test 5"?

One solution would be to create a very long if statement that displays this message if the day of week entered does not match any of the 29 valid day-of-week entries (e.g. "Monday," "monday," "Mon," "mon," "Tuesday," "tuesday" . . . ). However, I would like to find a simpler approach.

Thank you for your help!

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <iostream>
//Program in progress. Completing as part of my independent study of Programming: Principles and Practice by Bjarne Stroustrup.

int main()  
{
    string dayofweek;
    int value;

    vector<int> mondayvalues;
    vector<int> tuesdayvalues;
    vector<int> wednesdayvalues;
    vector<int> thursdayvalues;
    vector<int> fridayvalues;
    vector<int> saturdayvalues;
    vector<int> sundayvalues;
    int incorrectentrycounter = 0;
    int mondaysum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter days of the week followed by values in integer form. When you are finished, please enter Done 0.\n";
    string incorrectnumdump;

    while (cin) {
        if (cin >> dayofweek >> value) {
            if (dayofweek == "Monday" || dayofweek == "monday" || dayofweek == "Mon" || dayofweek == "mon") {
                mondayvalues.push_back(value);
            }

            if ((dayofweek == "Done") && (value == 0)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin >> incorrectnumdump;
            cout << "Incorrect day of week detected; please try again.\n";
            incorrectentrycounter++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    cout << "Here are the values you entered for each day of the week, along with their sums:\n";
    cout << "Monday: ";
    for (int x : mondayvalues)
        cout << x << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < mondayvalues.size(); i++) {
        mondaysum += mondayvalues[i];
    }
    cout << "\nSum of Monday values: " << mondaysum;
    cout << "\nThere were " << incorrectentrycounter << "entries that displayed non-valid days of the week.";
}
```

Comment: Can you please clean up and fix the indentation of the shown code. The shown code is pretty much unreadable due to the completely broken indentation.

Comment: In order to not have a giant if statement, you can use an `unordered_set` to have all the valid days, then do a `find` to see if the entered value is in that set.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good point. Looks like another user cleaned it up. Thank you to that user!

Comment: I'm also a fan of regular expressions. You could check the number of inputted words and, if correct, compare the value for the day of the week against your regular expression.

Comment: In other news, I learned about Alt + Shift + F in Visual Studio Code tonight, so no more displeasing indentation :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. Maybe you can use an ASCII technique to internally flip all inputs to either all caps or all small letters so that you won't have to look for both cases in your if statements as long as caps or small letters doesn't matter.
Make a function that takes the inputs and converts them to all caps or all small. Use this function before assigning the inputs to your variables. This will make checking them easier.
After that, you could create a const array[7] of std::string that will include all days. You can check your inputs by a method of elimination. You will be comparing input and array days letter by later and eliminating the days that don't match each time. If all days are eliminated then wrong input. If 2 or more days remain - input not sufficient. If 1 day remains that's the correct input!
Lemme know if you need help

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the code, I settled on this solution, which I think will meet my needs. The code now has two invalid entry statement blocks instead of one. The first ("Incorrect day of week detected") is within the `if (cin >> dayofweek >> value)` condition, and will identify dayofweek entries that don't match one of the Monday strings or Done.

The second ("Invalid entry") is outside the `if (cin >> dayofweek >> value)` condition but within the `while (cin)` condition. I added this second one so that if someone enters something like "test test," they will be notified of the error but the while loop will still continue.

So it seems as though when the user needs to enter multiple values via cin >>, one approach to input validation can be to enter multiple error messages at different levels of the code.

This solution is still a little clunky, but allows me to capture invalid entry with just "else" {} rather than "else" followed by a long set of conditions.

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <iostream>
//Program in progress. Completing as part of my independent study of Programming: Principles and Practice by Bjarne Stroustrup.

int main()
{
    string dayofweek;
    int value;

    vector<int> mondayvalues;
    vector<int> tuesdayvalues;
    vector<int> wednesdayvalues;
    vector<int> thursdayvalues;
    vector<int> fridayvalues;
    vector<int> saturdayvalues;
    vector<int> sundayvalues;
    int incorrectentrycounter = 0;
    int mondaysum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter days of the week followed by values in integer form. When you are finished, please enter Done 0.\n";
    string incorrectnumdump;

    while (cin)
    {
        if (cin >> dayofweek >> value)
        {
            if (dayofweek == "Monday" || dayofweek == "monday" || dayofweek == "Mon" || dayofweek == "mon")
            {
                mondayvalues.push_back(value);
            }

            else if ((dayofweek == "Done") && (value == 0))
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
                cout << "Incorrect day of week detected; please try again.\n";
                incorrectentrycounter++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
            cout << "Invalid entry; please try again.\n";
            incorrectentrycounter++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    cout << "Here are the values you entered for each day of the week, along with their sums:\n";
    cout << "Monday: ";
    for (int x : mondayvalues)
        cout << x << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < mondayvalues.size(); i++)
    {
        mondaysum += mondayvalues[i];
    }
    cout << "\nSum of Monday values: " << mondaysum << "\n";

    cout << "\nThere were " << incorrectentrycounter << " invalid entries.";
}
```